# Post process URLs to include language code and location

Tags: django, url-rewriting, middleware

I'm trying to have the URLs on my app being rendered as `/<language-code>/<city>/rest/of/url/`, with the language code being the currently active language and the city being a location the user selects....it's a bit like what's being done at [Heart](http://www.heart.co.uk/), but now with the i18n bit included.

How can I go about enabling this for my site?  I'm leaning towards a middleware solution as I believe this will be easy to use and will not involve modifications to the existing URLs.  Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - I created that functionality for Heart, and I never thought anyone would want to replicate it anywhere..

In any case, assuming you're talking about the outputting of URLs within links on regionalised pages, we did achieve that in middleware. I actually wrote [a blog post](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/02/1/middleware-post-processing-django-gotcha/) about it - the post is really about a separate issue, but does provide example code.

Comment: I've managed to get the code working from your example post, though I changed little of the code as we kinda want the same thing, the only bit I'm getting confused about is how to exclude my CSS and JS from being rewritten.  I'm also wondering if a cookie is effective for storing the city slug as that's what I'm using

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem Daniel...thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)  It seems you're a regular life saver as you've answered a good number of my questions

Comment: Danile...could you have an idea on how I can have external links (or other specified links on the same project) now being rewitten?  I've been trying to get a solution to this for several days without much success